# Flask problem when the user looks at the page source code

Tags: python, flask, post

I have noticed that after a POST, if you look at the page source via "control + U" flask opens the source page also again via POST and does all tasks again. Is there any way I can prevent this?

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def event_page():
if request.method == "POST":
   do_something()
```

when I view the source page the `do_something()` function is trigger t again.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Flask problem. The simplest solutions would be not to use CTRL+U but F12 - inspector or network tab

Comment: I can't control what the user will do. So it's a problem :l

Comment: In that case you can try using a nonce variable. On the client side you add an ever increasing number and on the server side you only do changes if the nonce in request is higher than the previous one.

You need to handle the number overflowing, i.e. going from MAX_INT to 0 or MIN_INT, e.g. if you're using short-lived sessions, you can simply store that number in session

Comment: thanks. that was what I did in the end